# Send email in php with attached file that is generated from database

Tags: php, email, email-attachments, vcf-vcard

I have a simple script for sending an email with an attachment that the user uploads.  How do I modify the script so that it would email a file that is generated in php (for an example, in this case, I want to pull the contact information from the database, generate a vCard of the file and have it attached to the email.

ViewCompany.php

```
<?php
// this auto-magically inserts header.html here
require('header.html');  


include('mail.php');

if(isset($_POST['name'], $_FILES['file'])){

    $body = array(

        "From: {$_POST['name']}",

        "Details:",
        "Name: {$_FILES['file']['name']}",
        "Size: {$_FILES['file']['size']}",
        "Type: {$_FILES['file']['type']}"

    );


    mail_file('receiver@email.com','sender@email.com','subject', implode("\r\n", $body), $_FILES['file']);

}
?>
```

---

```
<?php
echo    "<form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";
echo        "<p>";
echo            "<label for='name'>Name</label>";
echo            "<input type='text' name='name' id='name'>";
echo        "</p>";
//          $file = "getVcard.php?CompanyID=" . $CompanyID;

echo        "<p>";
echo            "<label for='file'>File</label>";
echo            "<input type='file' name='file' id='file'>";
echo        "</p>";

echo        "<p>";
echo            "<input type='submit' value='Email file'>";
echo        "</p>";
echo    "</form>";
?>
```

---

mail.php

```
<?php

function mail_file($to, $from, $subject, $body, $file){

    $boundary = md5(rand());

    $headers = array(
        "MIME-Version: 1.0",
        "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"{$boundary}\"",
        "From: {$from}"
    );

    $message = array(
        "--{$boundary}",
        "Content-Type: text/plain",
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit",
        "",
        chunk_split($body),
        "--{$boundary}",
        "Content-Type: {$file['type']}; name=\"{$file['name']}\"",
        "Content-Disposistion: attachment; fielname=\"{$file['name']}\"",
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64",
        "",
        chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file['tmp_name']))),
        "--{$boundary}--"
    );

    mail($to, $subject, implode("\r\n", $message), implode("\r\n", $headers));
}

?>
```

I tried to change

```
echo            "<label for='file'>File</label>";
echo            "<input type='file' name='file' id='file'>";
```

to

```
$file = "getVcard.php?CompanyID=" . $CompanyID;
```

to generate the vcard, but when I do this, the email does not send.

Any suggestions?

Thank you,

CampSoup1988

---

This is my getVcard.php file:

```
<?php
include "connection.php";
$CompanyID = $_GET['CompanyID'];
$CompanyID=$_GET['CompanyID']; // Collecting data from query string
if(!is_numeric($CompanyID)){ // Checking data it is a number or not
    echo "Data Error"; 
exit;
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM company where CompanyID = $CompanyID";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
header('Content-Type: text/vcard');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=vcardexport.vcf');
        while($ResultsLists = mysql_fetch_array($result)){  
echo                "BEGIN:VCARD\n";
echo                "VERSION:4.0\n";
echo                "KIND:org\n";
echo                "FN:" . $ResultsLists['CompanyName'] . "\n";
echo                "ORG:" . $ResultsLists['CompanyName'] . "\n";
echo                "ADR;TYPE=work;LABEL=\"". $ResultsLists['CompanyAddress1'] . "\n" . $ResultsLists['CompanyAddress2'] . "\n". $ResultsLists['CompanyCity'] . "\, " . $ResultsLists['CompanyState'] . " " . $ResultsLists['CompanyZipcode'] . "\n" . $ResultsLists['CompanyCountry'] . "\":" .  $ResultsLists['CompanyAddress2'] . ";" . $ResultsLists['CompanyAddress1'] . ";" . $ResultsLists['CompanyCity'] . ";" . $ResultsLists['CompanyState'] . ";" . $ResultsLists['CompanyZipcode'] . ";" . $ResultsLists['CompanyCountry'] . "\n";
                if($ResultsLists['CompanyPhone'] != ""){
echo                    "TEL;TYPE=\"work,voice\";VALUE=uri:tel:" . $ResultsLists['CompanyPhone'] . "\n";
                }
                if($ResultsLists['CompanyEmail'] != ""){
echo                    "WORK.EMAIL:" . $ResultsLists['CompanyEmail'] . "\n";
                }
echo                "WORK.LANG;PREF=1:en\n";
                if($ResultsLists['CompanyNotes'] != ""){
echo                    "NOTE:" . $ResultsLists['CompanyNotes'] . "\n";
                }
                if($ResultsLists['CompanyWebsite'] != ""){
echo                    "URL:" . $ResultsLists['CompanyWebsite'] . "\n";
                }
echo                "END:VCARD";
?>
```

---

**UPDATE:**  Is it possible to save the vcf file to a temp location and then automatically attaching the temp file to an email (renaming the temp file before attaching it to the email)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution would be to pass the data of your vcard by hand:

```
$file = array(
              'type' => 'text/plain',
              'name' => 'vcard.txt',
              'tmp_name' => 'http://yourdomain/getVcard.php?CompanyID=' . $CompanyID
        );
```

But that is a very dirty solution. In the long run it will be better to use a class like [phpmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/).

Comment: I was unable to get your suggest to work, I got no errors, but the email did not go.  I tried looking at phpmailer, but I was unsure how to set it up.  I am using XAMPP and the Mercury Mail that comes bundled with it, and set the Mercury Mail to send the email via gmail SMTP

Comment: hm, this code should work. Is the email send? Remember to define $file in your mail function or it will use other values. // You can define the smtp data in phpmailer directly. But I understand if this is too hard to do at the moment. Anyway you should get familiar with it or with similar classes.

Comment: I am not getting any emails.  I will edit the my original message to post the cost that is generating the vCards.  I tried changing the type to text/vcard and the file to vcard.vcf, and that did not work either.  I admit I am still a beginner when it comes to php, and I had never tried sending emails before, and used a tutorial to set up Mercury as well as a tutorial for the email script.