# Save vCard file to temp location before attaching to email

Tags: php, email, email-attachments, vcf-vcard, temporary-files

Is it possible to save a vcf file that was dynamically generated from information from a database to a temp location and then automatically attaching the temp file to an email (renaming the temp file before attaching it to the email)

PS: Yes, I am re-asking my previous question, which you could find [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10875464/send-email-in-php-with-attached-file-that-is-generated-from-database) but with a new alternative solution to my question